# jQueryMobile: Overflowing in iPad Landscape

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am hosting a `super simple` jQuery page in a WebView on an iPad. In Landscape mode, the text overflows off the right side. In Portrait it's fine. On an iPhone it's fine on all settings.

Is there a way to have it not overflow to the right?

The HTML is hosted on the app's WebViewController, not a web site.

Here's the head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css' />
        <script src='jquery-1.6.4.min.js'></script>
        <script src='jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role='page'>
            <div data-role='content'>
                Absolute permeability
                <br>
                <br>
                A measure of the ability of a single <a href='DEF:fluid'>fluid</a> (such as water, gas, or <a href='DEF:oil'>oil</a>) to flow through a rock <a href='DEF:formation'>formation</a> when the <a href='DEF:formation'>formation</a> is totally filled (saturated) with a single <a href='DEF:fluid'>fluid</a>. the <a href='DEF:permeability'>permeability</a> measure of a rock filled with a single <a href='DEF:fluid'>fluid</a> is different from the <a href='DEF:permeability'>permeability</a> measure of the same rock filled with two or more fluids. see effective <a href='DEF:permeability'>permeability</a>.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Got a link to your page?  Or HTML?  Or something?

Comment: I have added the HTML sent to the iOS control

Comment: what about wrapping the long line of text in a <p> tag?

Comment: Adding a <p> did not make a difference. It is strange that it only appears in Landscape which makes me think it's a rendering issue in the framework.